# How can I save state between orientations?

Tags: java, android, configuration, orientation

In a previous question I asked how I could display two different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations:

[Problem switching to landscape orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638467/app-crashes-when-switching-to-landscape-layout)

Now I would like to know how I can save the state of my application before it goes into another orientation? I seem to lose this data any time orientation changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of quesiton has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android).

But there are also other ways not listed in the previous answer. For example using the [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) method, as [explained here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actstate). This method is the advised way of storing state between configuration changes, and was poorly documented until recently.